# Convert a string which is list to list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like

```
query
-----------
[]
[(apple,10),(orange,15)]
[(apple,2),(orange,5)]
```

python is reading this as a string instead of a list because when I do 
`df['query'].apply(lambda x: len(x))`
I get 2 instead of 0 for the first row. Is there a way to convert this to a list.

Comment: `df['query'].apply(lambda x: len(ast.literal_eval(x)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
df['query'] = df['query'].apply(lambda x: x.strip('[]').split(','))
```

os, by list comprehension:

```
df['query'] = [x.strip('[]').split(',') for x in df['query']]
```

or, use [ast.literal_eval()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html):

```
import ast
df['query'] = df['query'].apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x))
```

or,

```
df['query'] = df['query'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
```